# Websocket in more pages

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

I create a simple login/password html5 application. Login/password I send via websocket to server to control and set in server side some permissions etc. 
How can I connect to this socket in next pages and server can sending correct data which permissions available etc.

Or this login password have I sending always when I connect to socket in every page?

Answer (score 1):

You can store token/session id in cookie.

On following navigation pages you can send that token to websocket to authenticate. Upon successful authentication you can response.

P.S. you need to create new websocket on every page load.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular web authentication using cookies.

WebSocket HTTP negotiation will carry cookies over. So you can return a cookie when the user connects with an generated UID if there is no any in the request, and then when the user authenticates, consider that UID as authenticated and associated with a User. Each time you get a connection with that UID you know it is that User.